# Onclick change visibility of a class

Tags: jquery, css

I have a series of buttons and a UL in which all list items have an inline style of display:none.

When the user clicks a button, I'd like to make visible any LIs with a certain class.  As an example, my code (complete with non-functioning jQuery!) looks like:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.countrySelect').click(function() {
        $(.Canada)
        .css('display','block')
    });
});
</script>

<button type="button" class="countrySelect" name="United-Kingdom">UK</button>
<button type="button" class="countrySelect" name="European-Union">EU</button>
<button type="button" class="countrySelect" name="Canada">Canada</button>

<ul>
  <li><span class="United-States Hosted">Amazon Flexible Payment System</span></li>
  <li><span class="United-States Hosted">Amazon Simple Pay</span></li>
  <li><span class="United-States Canada Onsite">Authorize.net</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: need quotes around .Canada like this: `$(".Canada")`

Answer (score 3):

```
 $('.countrySelect').click(function() {
        $(".Canada").css('display','block');
    });
```

[read more](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) about jQuery selectors

Comment: He can also use $('.Canada').hide(); or $('.Canada').fadeOut();

Comment: I've always used this. This also works for changing any CSS property.

Comment: @ClaudioLudovicoPanetta  you can use `$('.Canada').hide();  $('.Canada').fadeOut();` as is.. they are perfectly fine;

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.countrySelect').click(function() {
        $(".Canada").show();
    });
});
```

You needed quotes around the selector, and you might find that show() is a tad simpler (especially since `<span>` tags are display: inline by default, not display: block).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing out quotes with `.Canada` here. Try out in this way :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.countrySelect').click(function() {
        $('.Canada').css('color','red')
    });
});
```

Here is the working example : http://jsfiddle.net/SrpVG/